# toggleClass not working in live

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have a problem below is my code. i have use toggleClass and passed a css class in it. Now if i use without live() method it is working fine. But if i use with live() method it is not working i am stuck into this problem.

//Without live() method and it is working fine

```
$('#shownColumnsDiv tbody tr').click(function () {
        globalMove = $(this);
        globalArray.push(globalMove);
        index = $('#shownColumnsDiv tbody tr').index(this);
        alert(index);
        globalMove.toggleClass('highlight');            
    });
```

//With live() method it is not working fine

```
$('#shownColumnsDiv tbody tr').live("click", function(){
        globalMove = $(this);
        globalArray.push(globalMove);
        index = $('#shownColumnsDiv tbody tr').index(this);
        alert(index);
        globalMove.toggleClass('highlight');
    });
```

//this is a css portion

```
.highlight {
background-color: #0078ae;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: where are you regestering this event , its in document.ready right??

Comment: yeah i am registering the event.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
globalMove.toggleClass('highlight');
```

`globalMove` is already a jQuery object, because you stored `$(this)` in it, why would you want to generate a jQuery object of the jQuery object by writing `$(globalMove)`?

[Looks like it's working fine for me?](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/rky7g/)

Comment: @Shef...i was doing this in the same way as you have said rite now globalMove.toggleClass('highlight'); it was also not working at that time. so i changed to $(globalMove).toggleClass('highlight');

Comment: @Java_NewBie: It is working fine for me. Check the link on my answer. Maybe you have an error on another part of the code, which will prevent JS from running?

Comment: It is working in Fiddle.yeah may be you are rite...i am going to check my code again...

Comment: it is working fine for predefine <tr><td><td></td> that are already in DOM. but when it comes to dynamic like adding <tr><td><td></td> on click, then the issue comes on toggleClass.

Comment: @Java_NewBie: [Seems like it's working even for dynamic html](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/rky7g/)?

Comment: @Shef...i got the solution..its from another div which i am moving tr to another div. so i made that div also in live() method...now it is working fine. Thanks for the help Shef.

Answer (score 0):

use `.on` instead of live.

it is now no longer recommeded.
Now with .live() being deprecated in jQuery version 1.7 and removed in version 1.9, we need to use the .on() method. Here's an equivalent example using the .on() method:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', doSomething);

function doSomething() {
    // do something
}
```